# WordPress. как добавить свой собственный код

Tags: javascript, wordpress, плагин

Программирую совсем недавно(полтора месяца). Собрался устраиваться на trainee frontend dev. И получил ТЗ реализовать адаптивный(чтобы корректно работал на всех устройствах) калькулятор. В vsc я бы без проблем это реализовал.
Вычитал, что нужно создать свой плагин, я проделал все инструкции, он у меня показывается на WP. Собственно вопрос. Куда добавить мой код с калькулятором? Есть несколько полей в HTML форме и сам скрипт, совершенно не понимаю куда его добавлять.

Comment: Гуглил, узнал, что есть плагины, которые позволяют добавлять свой собственный js код.  Но посмотрев их описание, я так понял, что не совсем они подходят под вышеописанную мною задачу

Comment: 1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Написание_плагина 2. https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script